# Confusion about Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The two following theorems appear to be contradictory to me. I'm sure I must have overlooked something significant here.

[image]
[image]

The **Poincaré-Bendixson II(a)** says that if $R$ is a Type I invariant region, and **has a finite number of nodes or spiral points**, then given any initial position $X_0$ in $R$, $\lim_{t\to \infty}=X_1$ for some critical point $X_1$.

But how can this be possible? That the region $R$ has a finite number of nodes or spiral points, yet has no periodic solutions in $R$. Because Poincaré-Bendixson I(a) says that if $R$ is a Type I region that *has a single unstable note or an unstable spiral point in its interior* (and thus has a finite number of nodes or spiral points), then there must be at least one periodic solution in $R$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two versions of the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem are not contradicting each other. Instead, I think you overlooked some of the hypotheses.

The first theorem tells you that a positively invariant, compact subset of the phase plane always contains at least one closed orbit, provided there are no fixed points in it (or provided it has just one *unstable* node or spiral point in its interior). While the proof of this fact relies on the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ a lot, the idea behind its formulation is easy to understand: if a trajectory is trapped in a compact subset of the phase plane which does not contain any stable fixed points, then it would have nothing to do but to approach a limit cycle.

The second theorem relies on *different* hypotheses: $R$ is still a positively invariant, compact subset of the phase plane, but it does not contain any periodic solutions now. So you should ask yourself: if a solution is forever trapped in $R$, and there are no limit cycles to be approached, what can that solution possibly do? Flowing toward a *stable* equilibrium point, of course. Indeed, this answers your question: it is possible to have a region $R$ that is a positively invariant, compact subset of the phase plane, with no periodic solutions in it, that still contains a finite number of nodes or spiral points: you'd just need some of those fixed points to be *stable*.

Also, pay attention to the fact your book says nothing about a positively invariant, compact subset of the phase plane that is both free from equilibrium points and limit cycles. Such a region cannot exist, and this is the very ***essence*** of the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem: once you manage to trap a solution inside a region like $R$, then it can only either approach a (stable) fixed point, or spiral toward a limit cycle.

---

There's actually a third possibility, that of approaching a more complicated object called a *cycle graph* (which consists of a finite number of fixed points together with the orbits connecting them). Yet the spirit of the theorem does not change: a bounded solution may not wander in a chaotic fashion, because nothing different from approaching a stable fixed point, a limit cycle or a cycle graph is allowed. As a matter of fact, the Poincaré-Bendixson Theorem is what tells you that chaos can never occur in a two-dimensional dynamical system.

Comment: The last one is usually called _heteroclinic cycle_ or _polycycle_, as far as I remember